# passing char* args[] via voidpointer

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Her is my simplified code:

```
void main(){
    void* ptr;
    char* args[3];
    args[0]="Arg1";
    args[1]="Arg2";
    args[2]="Arg3";
    ptr = &args;

    myMethod(ptr);
}
static void myMethod(void* args){

}
```

how can I convert `void* args` to an `char*[]`? in `myMethod(void*)`?

Answer (score 6):

You want a pointer to pointer to `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void myMethod(void *args)
{
    char **ptr = args;

    printf("%s\n", ptr[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    void *ptr;
    char *args[3];

    args[0]="Arg1";
    args[1]="Arg2";
    args[2]="Arg3";
    ptr = args; /* You don't need the & */

    myMethod(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by @Eregrith, pass the number of cells to the function in order to prevent an out of bounds access:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void myMethod(void *args, size_t elems)
{
    char **ptr = args;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < elems; i++)
        printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    void *ptr;
    char *args[3];

    args[0]="Arg1";
    args[1]="Arg2";
    args[2]="Arg3";
    ptr = args;

    myMethod(ptr, sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would advise also passing the actuel number of cells in your array in order to avoid potential out-of-bonds-ing

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how to cast "char* []".

Comment: @user2071938, you are welcome, also note that you can pass `args` directly to the function (there is no need to use `ptr` in the main function)